# Troubleshooting nested IF function

Tags: microsoft-excel, function-keys

I am having trouble with the [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) in the example below.

Conditions:

- There are 3 exams and one total score.
- The student has to score at least 5 points in each exams to pass.
- If he has in one of the exams a score of 4 or less points he fails.
- However, the total score has to be >=16 to pass, otherwise he also fails.

**Example 1:**

> Test 1 = 4, Test 2 = 10, Test 3 = 10, Total = 24; he has
>   more than 16 but fails because he got a 4 in one of the exams.

**Example 2:**

> Test 1 = 5, Test 2 = 5, Test 3 = 5, Total =15; fails again
>   because the total score is under 16.

**Problem:**

I used this function:

```
=IF(E4>=5;IF(F4>=5;IF(G4>=5;IF(H4>=16;"Pass";"Fail"))))
```

It works fine except in the scenario where the student gets a 4 or less in one of the exams. When this happens, I get `FALSE` but I want it to be `Fail`.

**Screenshot:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM6rk.png]

Comment: You've provided true and false values for the inner-most nested IF, but none of the others.  You can do this with AND: =IF(AND(E4>=5,F4>=5,G4>=5,H4>=16);"Pass";"Fail")

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply and of course it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by *@fixer1234*:

Use the [AND function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) within the [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) to check for multiple conditions and reduce complexity:

```
=IF(AND(E4>=5,F4>=5,G4>=5,H4>=16);"Pass";"Fail")
```